SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1006)')))
I am building an assistant using OPENAI. The app allows users to send SMS messages to africastalking which is basically Africa's version of twilio. Once users send sms, it will be received by chatgpt and send back a response to the user. However, i get the following error:
   raise new_e
   raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason # type: ignore[arg-type]

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.sandbox.africastalking.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /version1/messaging (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1006)')))

My code is as follows: code in my main.py:
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

from africastalking_chatbot.helper.openai_api import chat_completion
from africastalking_chatbot.helper.africastalking_api import response_to_sms

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return 'OK', 200

@app.route('/sms_callback', methods=['POST'])
def sms_callback():
    data = request.form
    print(f'Data - {data}')
    query = data.get('text')
    print(f'Query - {query}')
    recipients = data.get('from')
    print(f'Recipients - {recipients}')
    response = chat_completion(query)
    print(f'Response - {response}')
    #This is where it starts to fail
    response_to_sms(recipients, response)
    print('Message Sent.')
    return 'Success', 200

Code in C:\Users\Kepha\africastalking_gpt\africastalking_chatbot\helper\africastalking_api.py:
import africastalking
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from config import config

#Initialize SDK
username = config.AFRICASTALKING_USERNAME
api_key = config.AFRICASTALKING_API_KEY

africastalking.initialize(username, api_key)

# Initialize service e.g SMS
sms = africastalking.SMS

def response_to_sms(recipient_phone_number, message):
  requests.post(
      "http://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/messaging",
      data = {
          "username": "sandbox",
          "to": recipient_phone_number,
          "message": message,
          "from": "xxxxxx" # add shortcode here
      },

      headers = {
          "apiKey": api_key ,
          "Accept": "application/json" ,
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
  )

Code in openai_api.py:
import openai
import requests
from config import config

openai.api_key = config.OPENAI_API_KEY

def chat_completion(prompt: str) -> str:
  try:
    completion = openai.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
      {"role": "system", "content":config.INSTRUCTIONS},
      {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
    ]
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message
  except:
    return config.ERROR_MESSAGE

I am able to get a response back from openai , the code seems to fail from this part:
  response_to_sms(recipients, response)
    print('Message Sent.')
    return 'Success', 200

Cant seem to figure out where the error is. I have looked at a number of articles and the proposed solution is to change url in this part from https to http:
    requests.post(
      "http://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/messaging",
      data = {
          "username": "sandbox",
          "to": recipient_phone_number,
          "message": message,
          "from": "xxxx" # add shortcode here
      },


The error you get can have a variety of reasons. The most obvious one based on the error message is that you are running a very old software stack which has no support for modern TLS - the site requires at least TLS 1.2. But the more likely option is that you talk HTTPS (HTTP over TLS) to and endpoint which responds with plain HTTP. This is the case with wrong local proxy configuration, captive portal denying access or some middlebox (firewall, ...) blocking access. Unfortunately nothing is known about your environment, so one can only speculate.

And just changing from https:// to http:// will not help (whatever "number of articles" made such recommendation) - it will redirect you back to https:// so nothing achieved.
